# How to return / GET two models/tables from my DB in one controller / JOIN or use stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create get request that when provided with a broker ID, it returns all the broker information from the Broker table and all of the brokers Applications from the Application table. The two tables are joined by broker ID.

I have tried a few methods found on stakoverflow but keep hitting errors.

```
public class BrokerApplications
    {
        public virtual ICollection<Broker> Broker { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<BrokerApplications>> GetBrokerApplicationsAsync(int brokerID)
        {
                var brokerApps = (from b in _context.Broker
                                  join a in _context.Application on b.BrokerId equals a.BrokerId
                                  where a.BrokerId == brokerID
                                  //            select new { b.BrokerForename, b.BrokerId, a.RollNumber, a.CustomerFullName }
                                  //).ToList();
                                  select a);
    
                return brokerApps;
}
```

But got an error message saying

> "cs0029:cannot implicitly covert type
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SMWEBAPI.Models.Application> to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<SMWebAPI.Controllers.BrokerAppsController.BrokerApplicattions>

This is when I tried

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetBrokerApplicationsAsync(int brokerID)
{
var broker = await _context.Broker.FindAsync(brokerID);

```
            BrokerApplications BrokerApps = new BrokerApplications();

            List<Application> lstApps = new List<Application>();
            lstApps = (List<Application>)_context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID);
            BrokerApps.Broker = (ICollection<Broker>)broker.ToList();
            BrokerApps.Applications = lstApps;

            return BrokerApps;
```

}

but this return the following error message when I tried to call from the URL

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[SMWebAPI.Models.Application]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SMWebAPI.Models.Application]'.
> SMWebAPI.Controllers.BrokerAppsController.GetBrokerApplications(int
> brokerID) in BrokerAppsController.cs
> +
> lstApps = (List)_context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID);

Can someone please help me in how to return from this Get method when provided with a brokerID please?

---

UPDATE

I haven't been able to return the data as of yet, as when I used a method that didn't give me any errors it returned an empty array.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<BrokerApplications>> GetBrokerApplicationsAsync(int brokerID)
    {
        return new BrokerApplications()
        {
            Broker = await _context.Broker.Where(x => x.BrokerId == brokerID).ToListAsync(),
            Applications = await _context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID).ToListAsync()
        };
    }
```

SO...

I wanted to find another way to get the data.

I have created a stored procedure

```
    -- =======================================================
-- Create Stored Procedure Template for Azure SQL Database
-- =======================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author, , Name>
-- Create Date: <Create Date, , >
-- Description: <Description, , >
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE ApplicationsByBroker
(
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @brokerId int
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT dbo.Application.*, dbo.Broker.*
  FROM dbo.Application, dbo.Broker
WHERE (dbo.Broker.BrokerID = @brokerId AND dbo.Application.BrokerID = 
    @brokerId)

    END
    GO
```

I ran this to ensure it worked using

```
USE SecuredMessagingDatabase;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.ApplicationsByBroker @BrokerId = 1000001;
```

And I got the expected results, How would I execute this in my web api?

Comment: If you set this up correctly, `Broker` should have property `Applications` that you can populate by `Include`. Then all you have to return is a `Broker` object.

Comment: Try this ```lstApps=await _context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID).ToListAsync()```

Comment: lstApps = (List<Application>)_context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID); ->This line must be tolist ()

Comment: From what I see you're only sinking deeper. Just add `Broker.Applications` as navigation property and it will all be one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `Include` if two objects have a relation by `BorkerId`, but you can write like this to solve the problem:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<BrokerApplications>> GetBrokerApplicationsAsync(int brokerID)
{
   return new BrokerApplications()
   {
    Broker = await _context.Broker.Where(x=>x.Id==brokerID).ToListAsync(),
    Applications = await _context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID).ToListAsync()
   };

  
}
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't give me any error's (yey) but when i use a valid broker ID it just returns an empty array in both broker and application. I have set Broker to have a one to many relation with application but im not sure how to use Include?

Comment: I think you should check data in database to choose a valid brokerId and debug your code.

Comment: To use ``include``: use this ``return await _context.Broker.Include(x=>x.Applicarions).Where(x=>x.Id==brokerID).ToListAsync();`` and your action response should be ``Task<ActionResult<List<Broker>>>``

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query, which have one roundtrip to database. I hope EF will not fail.

```
class BrokerApplication
{
   public Broker Broker {get; set;)
   public Application Application {get; set;)
}

[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<BrokerApplications>> GetBrokerApplicationsAsync(int brokerID)
{
   var brokers = _context.Broker.Where(x => x.Id == brokerID)
      .Select(b => new BrokerApplication { Broker = b });

   var applications = _context.Application.Where(a => a.BrokerId == brokerID) 
      .Select(a => new BrokerApplication { Application = a });

   var combined = await brokers.Concat(applications).ToListAsync();

   var result = BrokerApplications
   {
     Broker = combined.Where(c => c.Broker != null)
       .Select(c => c.Broker).ToList(),
     Applications = combined.Where(c => c.Application != null)
       .Select(c => c.Application).ToList()
   };
 
   return result;
}
```